# $(".sth").attr("id"); returns multiple values, undefined as first

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Following piece of code produces two alert boxes, first one containing `undefined`, and second one containing the id attribute. when I add `return false` to the end, it only shows `undefined`, and doesnt return the id. I'm quite new in this jquery thing. The idea behind this code is, when you click on `<a href="/abcd" id="abc"></a>`, show the `<ul class="abc"></ul>`, which has its *display* initially set to *none*.

```
$(".navgbr-itm").click(function(){
  target_menu = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(target_menu);
  //$("."+target_menu).toggle();
});
```

I use jquery 1.8.2 and the jquery-ui 1.9 . I'm using jquery ui for sth not related to this snippet (for an image slider). And as a note, I have to cancel the navigation after the click.

html:

```
<nav id="main-navgbr" class="htmlf-block">  
    <ul id="main-navgbr-itms" class="navgbr-itms">  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-academc" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/akademik" class="navgbr-itm">Akademik</a></li>  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-idari" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/idari" class="navgbr-itm">İdari / Personel</a></li>  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-ogrn" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/ogrenci" class="navgbr-itm">Öğrenci</a></li>  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-arastr" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/arastirma" class="navgbr-itm">Araştırma</a></li>  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-hast" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/hastaneler" class="navgbr-itm">Hastaneler</a></li>  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-ktph" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/kutuphane" class="navgbr-itm">Kütüphane</a></li>  
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-bshi" class="navgbr-itm"><a   
        href="/bshi" class="navgbr-itm">Basın / Halkla İlişkiler</a></li>   
      <li id="main-nvgbr-itm-blog" class="navgbr-itm"><a  
        href="/bloglar" class="navgbr-itm">Bloglar</a></li>  
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried the w3c validator with this page and it validates. I'm basically recreating my uni's website for training purposes. And this file is run via a `lighttpd` server.

Comment: Do you have two **nested** elements with the class `navgbr-itm`? That would explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<a href="#" class="menuitem" data-target-menu="mymenu">Click Me</a>

<ul id="mymenu" style="display:none;">
    <li>Submenu 1</li>
    <li>Submenu 2</li>
    <li>Submenu 3</li>
    <li>Submenu 4</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.menuitem').click(function() {
        $('ul#' + $(this).data('target-menu')).toggle();
    }
});
</script>
```

Here I introduce you to `$.data` jQuery utility. It helps you to store data in specific `"data-*"` attributes of your tag.

You can see more on jQuery Documentation:

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. But I cant get why .attr("id") retruns unidentified?

Comment: because ID in your case is undefined. Set it like id="something", and with .attr('id') or .prop('id') you'll get "something" in response. :)

Comment: `<li id="main-nvgbr-itm-academc" class="navgbr-itm">` this is my html, isn't *id* set for `.navgbr-itm` here? `a` tags are nested inside `li`s. So does this mean it returns the inner most first?

Comment: $('.navgbr-itm').click(function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); }); // this must work :)

Comment: have an email? contact me on: zlomerovic[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: Note that the `data-` attributes are part of HTML5 and not jQuery. Just saying, because you made it sounds like it is.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry about that, and thank you for noticing, and thank you on the info :)

Answer (score 0):

You have nested `.navgbr-item` elements in your HTML. That means that clicking on a link will trigger the event handler for both, the `a` and the `li` element. The `a` elements don't have IDs though, so you get `undefined`.

Instead of binding the event handler to both the `li` element and the `a` element, bind it to the `li` elements only:

```
$("li.navgbr-itm").click(function(){
  target_menu = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(target_menu);
  //$("."+target_menu).toggle();
});
```

[HTML5 `data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) are a good way to store the data too.

Comment: I solved the problem with data- attribute. Thanks for your help. As a little note, I have experienced that binding event to `li.class` doesn't work when the nested element is a block element. I used `$('a.navgbr-itm').toggle(function(){/*hide open menus and show selected*/},function(){/*hide all menus*/});`.

Comment: It should not matter what kind of element the child is. I'd assume you have something else going on in your code...